# Nginx server removes www and 301 redirects to wrong host

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a weird 301 redirection issue. My server is set up to handle multiple domains pointing to the server, i.e.

- The main domain: https://maindomain.com
- An N number of custom domains: http://somecustomdomain.com, http://anothercustomdomain.com, etc.

However there is a strange 301 issue when visiting a custom domain and including `www.`, like: http://www.somecustomdomain.com. On the maindomain this works fine:

- When visiting `https://www.maindomain.com/some-uri` it will redirect to: `https://maindomain.com/some-uri`

However, when visiting a custom domain it redirects from: `http://www.somecustomdomain.com/some-uri` to `https://maindomain.com/some-uri` (!!). You would expect it to redirect to: `http://somecustomdomain.com/some-uri`

I have tried debugging this issue (ensured that my browser does not cache the 301 redirects) and I have not been able to resolve the issue. I have three nginxs confiugrations inside my `sites-available` directory. They are listed here:

- `maindomain.com`
- `catch-all` (I have tried removing this file, so only `maindomain.com` exists, but problem still occours)
- `www.maindomain.com` (I have tried removing this file, so only `maindomain.com` exists, but problem still occours)

`maindomain.com` contents

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name maindomain.com;
    return 301 https://maindomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name maindomain.com;
    root /home/forge/maindomain.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/maindomain.com/30126/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/maindomain.com/30126/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/maindomain.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

`catch-all` contents

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.+)$;

    root /home/forge/maindomain.com/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/maindomain.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

`www.maindomain.com` contents

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.maindomain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://maindomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

If i CURL into `http://www.somecustomdomain.com/some-uri` this is the content I receive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://maindomain.com/some-uri" />

        <title>Redirecting to https://maindomain.com/some-uri</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="https://maindomain.com/some-uri">https://maindomain.com/some-uri</a>.
    </body>
</html>%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra server configuration for www domains:

```
server {
  server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;

  location / {
    return 301 $scheme://$domain/$uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried appending the server block but issue still persists. I have also tried replacing the server block with the block in `www.maindomain.com` but that does not work either. Strange issue is, even if I delete `www.maindomain.com`, I still get 301 redirected from www. to the one without. That makes me think some configuration elsewhere makes this redirect.

Comment: Update: I'll try to add it before I make the config inside catch-all, but now I am getting 301 too many redirects. It seems as though it 301 redirects both with and without www. in server name. @elDante

Comment: I finally got it working. Thanks! Your answer is edited